# Connecting Android Phone to computer without USB

Tags: data-transfer

Is there a way to connect my Android phone to my computer in the way a USB connection works without actually using USB?
I mean that it at least registers as an external drive and hopefully I'm also able to install programs when developing via Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

If you have WiFi, there are possibilities:

- you can use ADB over TCP (also called "wireless ADB"), see e.g. my list of [ADB solutions](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_adb)
- you can use [WebDAV](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_server_file#group_410) or [Samba](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_server_file#group_411) to share your "drives from the device" to your computer (note, however, that with Windows that would require your Android device to be rooted, as Windows cannot deal with Samba shares on "unusual ports")

Answer (score 1):

I don't about Samba but I had to follow many steps to setup WebDAV on my Windows 7. To avoid it, I propose using an [FTP server](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=ftp&c=apps&docType=1&sp=CAFiBQoDZnRwegIYAIoBAggB:S:ANO1ljJ3KMc) on Android and [mount it](http://lifehacker.com/300997/mount-remote-file-systems-with-netdrive) on Windows using [NetDrive](http://www.netdrive.net/) (also has an Android app [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bdrive.airdrive)) as an external drive. This works flawlessly and easily in my system.

You can also host an [SSH server](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=ssh+server&c=apps&docType=1&sp=CAFiDAoKc3NoIHNlcnZlcnoCGACKAQIIAQ%3D%3D:S:ANO1ljKZyrM) on Android and mount it using [win-sshfs](https://code.google.com/p/win-sshfs/).

I still favor the first solution for  easy job.